# passing a struct (buffer) to multiple function and tasks in FREERTOS

Tags: c, struct, parameter-passing, buffer, freertos

Please help.
in C, I have a struct with a buffer.  I need 12 copies of this struct buffer (total ~4600B), that needs to be passed to several task and functions, each will modify contents.
I also have a callback, that is in a separate FREERTOS task, that also needs to access the buffer (hard to pass a struct that is not created till later). – Note, I do not have any parameter passed to this task so far.
But wanted to avoid global fixed buffer.  Can I set a global buffer as a **pointer **(so not to waste fixed memory) , and then malloc in the first function ? so I can FREE() later when done ?
Do I need to malloc in each task for the same ota_buf?
Do I need to pass ota_buf struct to task2 ? or since a global is ok ?

```
void task2( void *parameter) {
ota_buff_t *ota_buf = malloc(sizeof(ota_buff_t)*12);
…
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].Nsdu[0] = 0xD1;
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].position  = 1;
…
set_buf1(&ota_buf);
….
Free(ota_buf)
}//end task 1

void task1 (void *parameter) {
While(1) {
//Do stuff
If (the malloc happens and data set) set_buf2(&ota_buf);
}//while
}//end task2

set_buf1 (ota_buff_t  **ota_buf) {
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].Nsdu[0] = 0xD2;
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].position  = 2;
} //end check_buf1()

set_buf2(ota_buff_t  **ota_buf) {
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].Nsdu[0] = 0xD3;
(ota_buf)[d1_ptr].position  = 3;
} //end check_buf2()

In helper:
typedef struct {
  uint8_t  Nsdu[400];
  uint16_t  position;
} ota_buff_t;

Global: ?
ota_buff_t *ota_buf = NULL;
int d1_ptr = 0;

Main() {
//create task1, loops forever
xTaskCreate(task1, "T1", 1024*8, NULL, 1, NULL);
….some time later: a one-time task
xTaskCreate(task2, "T2", 1024 * 8, NULL, 2, NULL);
}
```

so do i need to pass the struct to the task1 (even though when its called task2 has not malloc yet ?) or as a global pointer its ok if not used till after the malloc?

change to:

```
void task1( void *parameter) {
ota_buff_t ota_buf = *(ota_buff_t *) parameter;
While(1) {
//Do stuff
If (the malloc happens and data set) set_buf2(&ota_buf);
}//while
}//end task2


Main() {
//create task1, loops forever
xTaskCreate(task1, "T1", 1024*8, &ota_buf, 1, NULL);
….some time later: a one-time task
xTaskCreate(task2, "T2", 1024 * 8, NULL, 2, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I think i answered my own question by trial and error: its not possible.  when the buffer is initialized (malloc), the address changes from the initial NULL pointer.  going to have to think of another option...

Comment: "so not to waste fixed memory" You are being confused. Just because you allocate something on the heap instead, it isn't allocated in thin air. In fact the data takes up _more_ RAM space when placed on the heap, due to overhead. If you want to save memory, get rid of the heap entirely. Check out [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)